# Move or Copy Excel Sheet to Another Workbook (Destination workbook is named using variable)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy an excel worksheet into another excel workbook.  This generally wouldn't be too difficult, except I am moving my worksheet into a workbook that is saved using variables.

Here is a bit of my code:

```
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "a"
Sheets("Policy Search").Move After:=Workbooks(fname).Sheets(SheetName)
```

"policy search" will always be named the same, and this is the workbook I am trying to move.  However, I am trying to move it to a file that is dynamically saved using the variable "fname", and the sheet name "SheetName".

Every time I try and run this bit of code, I am getting a Subscript out of range error.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `fname` a string variable or a workbook variable?

Comment: String Variable.  Should I change it to workbook?

Comment: Does the sheet "Policy Search" exist?  Does the workbook referred to by `fname` exist and is it open?  Does that workbook contain a sheet referred to by the variable `SheetName`? (Or is that a typo and is meant to be `"SheetName"`?)

Comment: Does `fname` contain the fully qualified file name / path, or just the file name?  (The Workbooks object is indexed by the file name, not the name/path.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub MoveSheet()
    Sheets("Policy Search").Select
    Sheets("Policy Search").Move After:=Workbooks(fname).Sheets(SheetName)
End Sub
```

It assumes "Policy Search" is the active sheet.

Comment: That is actually what I had written earlier. Still getting same error. Thank you though.